# Datasource not working in JBoss 7.2

Tags: datasource, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

When I create a datasource, a service restart is required to make it work, regardless of the method used to create it (standalone.xml, JBoss CLI, JBoss Administration Console). Attached is the procedure I have written for my team (exported from our Wiki space). The datasource gets created successfully, but when I test the connection, I get this:

**From JBoss Administration Console**

```
Unknown error

Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "dsMyApp")
    ],
    "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010442: failed to match pool. Check JndiName: java:/dsMyApp",
    "rolled-back" => true,
    "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
}
```

**From JBoss CLI**

```
JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010442: failed to match pool. Check JndiName: java:/dsMyApp
```

If I restart the JBoss server, the datasource works fine (server, port, username and password are all correct).

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Quick Answer: **YES, restarting makes a reload and then activates the datasource**

I suggest you **doing a reload with jboss-cli** (It´s the quickest way)

I´ve created all my datasources with jboss-cli and I always need to
 perform this action to allow them to work. After the reload, the datasource connection can be tested.

```
/opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=192.168.119.116:9990 --commands="reload --host=master"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: How we can do the same for windows?? As I have tried restarting the server but it doesnt help. While using reload option I get "--host is not allowed in the standalone mode."